# How do you check the amount of occurrences in a string of a specific set of characters (not only one character)?

Tags: javascript

The problem here is that it only goes one time, meaning that no matter how many of the string "if" is put in, the bytenum is only down by 3. However, if this is put in a for loop, this happens: when a key is pressed, if there is a string "if," the bytenum decreases by three every time a key is pressed.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let js = document.getElementById('js');
let nes = document.getElementById('nes');
let bytenum = 40976;
let num = 0;
let flag;
let i = 0;

js.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Backspace" || event.key === "Delete") {
    flag = 0;
    forever();
  } else {
    flag = 1;
    forever();
  }
});

function forever() {
  if (i < num) {
    i++;
  }
  if (flag == 0 && num > 0) {
    num -= 1;
  } else if (flag == 1) {
    num += 1;
  }
  if (js.value[i] === "i" && js.value[i + 1] === "f") {
    bytenum -= 3;
    console.log(bytenum);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

forever();
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <h1>Input (.JS Format)</h1>
  <textarea id="js"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="output">
  <h1>Free Cartridge Space</h1>
  <textarea id="nes"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on key-down events and manual tracking with `i` and num, you can use a more straightforward method by scanning the entire text each time there's an input. This ensures that you count every occurrence of the substring correctly, regardless of how it's inputted or removed.

Check this out,

```
<div id="input">
<h1>Input (.JS Format)</h1>
<textarea id="js"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="output">
<h1>Free Cartridge Space</h1>
<textarea id="nes"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
let js = document.getElementById('js');
let nes = document.getElementById('nes');
let bytenum = 40976;

js.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const matches = js.value.match(/if/g); // Use a regular expression to find all occurrences of "if"
    const count = matches ? matches.length : 0; // If matches found, count them, otherwise 0
    bytenum = 40976 - (count * 3); // Adjust bytenum based on the number of occurrences
    nes.value = `Free Cartridge Space: ${bytenum}`; // Display the updated bytenum
});

</script>
```